# Matlab - Assign a matrix to an index of a variable

Tags: matlab, matrix

how can I get a matrix out of cell array?

here is my cell array:

```
d{1} = [[1 1]; [2 2]; [3 3]]
d{2} = [[1 2]; [2 3]]
```

I want to get the first matrix out of d{1} which should give me [1 1] but I tried this:

`d{1}(1)` and It only gives me the first element in the cell. How can I get it to return these cells as a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to access both columns of the first row. So, simply do this: `d{1}(1,:)`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!